# How to connect jade-agents (java) and babylon.js (html/javascript) - Servlet to html?

Tags: javascript, java, html, babylonjs, agents-jade

Summary:
IDE: Eclipse
Server: Java
Client: Html/Javascript
After sending data via ajax/jquery to a servlet and using JadeGateway to send those information to an agent, resulting data should go back to html/javascript.
I need a way to connect either a servlet or an agent with an existing and running html file (ofc without reloading the page).

Background:
I want to create a agent based game using babylon.js and jade/pug (let's call it jade).
During a game, information about game states should go to an agent, so that he could figure out what to do (e.g. create more units or attack). After this, the agent needs to send the information to the game, to call the appropriate function.

What I did so far:
I connected the game (html/javascript) with a servlet using ajax. There I used JadeGateway to send an ACLMessage to an agent.
I also used websockets to connect client/server but this method is too limited for what i need i think. 
I now need a tool/method or tips to send information from an agent or the servlet. Both is possible, because the agent can send information back to the jadegateway agent/servlet. 
I know how to use ajax to call a servlet from html and right back, but now the information is tranfered to some other classes, so that didn't work anymore.

In the babylon.js scene.registerBeforeRender function I do this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "AgentListenerServlet",
    type: "POST",
    data: {playerString: convertPlayerToJson(player1)},
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data.command)
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("Listener Failed")
    }
});
```

Sending message to an agent via jadegateway:

```
JadeGateway.execute(new CyclicBehaviour() {
    public void action() {
    final ACLMessage msgSend = new ACLMessage(ACLMessage.INFORM);
    msgSend.setContent(message);
    msgSend.addReceiver(new AID("First", AID.ISLOCALNAME));
    myAgent.send(msgSend);

    final ACLMessage msgReceive = myAgent.receive();
    if(msgReceive != null && msgReceive.getContent() != null){          
            //used this as immediate answer for ajax success function, but maybe it can also be used to send the returning agent message?
            Map <String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            map.put("command", "information");
            write(response, map);
      } else {
        block();
    }
    }
});

private void write(HttpServletResponse response, Map<String, Object> map) throws IOException {
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.getWriter().write(new Gson().toJson(map));
    }
```

agent code (simplified):

```
public void action() {
                final ACLMessage msgSend = new ACLMessage(ACLMessage.INFORM); //sending message
                final ACLMessage msgReceive = receive(); //receiving message

                    //Here i get information out of sent json objects from jadegateway
                    //Maybe here send handled information back to html?
          } else {
                    block();
                }
            }
```

Maybe showing this codes is not necessary, because they are working and the problem is not there, but the template for asking a question requested these.

Expected and results:
So the problem is not, that it isn't working, but that I need to know how to continue. 
I don't know what I expect, because i don't know the possibilities.
Maybe, what would help me, is to send a simple string from the agent or servlet that i can call with the alert function in the game.

Or maybe i should ask this: is it possible to get an answer in ajax (success function) after the data was sent to the servlet and passed to an agent?

Sorry for the huge spam. Hope I made my problem clear.

Comment: When you say Jade, you mean the multiagent platform right? Pug is a templating engine that used to be called jade so it's pretty confusing to even mention that otherwise

Answer (score 1):

No need to reply, websockets is the solution after all.
I just figured out, that you can push data from server to client without a client request with

```
session.getBasicRemote().sendText(msgReceive.getContent());
```

The session is automatically generated and you can reveice it with websockets onopen method:

```
    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session){
        this.session = session;
    }
```